# Using WSUS to update machines not on the domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus

I have a WSUS server providing updates for for the computers on my domain. We also bring allot of machines back to our office and run windows update on them as build image, this means that we end up downloading the same updates over and over again.

Is there anyway to get a machine to download its updates from our WSUS Server? i found that theres something running on port 8530 but its just an empty document, in fact every folder listed in IIS config returns a blank document

anyone know if this is possible? and how i would do it?

Just incase it wasnt clear, these machines update here as we image them then need to go out to all manner of networks, so it needs to be a non permernant connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes just [configure the machine to receive updates from your WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708449(WS.10).aspx), and it should do that right away (or you can provoke it by running wuauctl /detectnow). There should be no dependency on having a domain except for pushing the configuration with group policy.

Comment: I don't believe you have to use regedit. You should be able to do it all via gpedit. Use this tutorial instead: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512630.aspx Just edit the intranet location to OP's intranet server

It is much safer than editing registry keys.

Comment: Well I figured as this seemed to be a reoccurring requirement, a script of some kind will be needed in the end to at least partly automate it - but alternate ways are always good ^^

Comment: yeah im probabbly gonna have to write a script to change the settings, run an update and then change them back

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this article, it might help you set it up: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708449%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that the WSUS licence agreement specifically says that you cannot use WSUS to update computers not owned by your organisation, so if these PC's you are bringing out are not yours, then you could be breaking the licence agreement.

Not that there is anything that will stop you doing this but thought you should be aware.

Comment: well technically untill we invoice our customers the machines belong to us

Comment: @Arcath well that's fair enough then :)

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe you can do this, but Windows updates are fetched just using HTTP - so they can be cached by something like Squid or ISA Server. Each machine will download the updates in the normal fashion but your cache will serve it locally. I've had this work well prior to the existence of WSUS.